# Vertically centering img in Bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering, nav

I am putting two buttons inline on the nav bar. I got them there, but I can't seem to get them to center, they are getting pushed down outside of the nav bar. This is a simple bootstrap template.

Here is a link: [www.brybell.me/br1](http://www.brybell.me/br1)

```
<nav class="main nav-collapse visible-desktop">
   <ul class="inline">
      <!-- <li><a href=".home">Home</a></li> -->
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/appstore_button.png" alt="Get the iPhone App Now!" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/googleplay_button.png" alt="Get the Android App Now!" /></a></li>
      <li><a href=".our-team">Terms of Service</a></li>
      <li><a href=".privacy">Privacy</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<!-- /nav.main -->
```

That is what the nav html is, and this is the CSS that is controlling it currently.

```
nav.main ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    padding: 30px 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

I know this should be an easy fix. I tried making a new CSS rule but it just seemed to make it worse. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You put too much top padding
Try : padding: 10px 10px;

Comment: This also works but then moves the other two text links up as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `line-height` of the `<a>` the same as the `height` of the `header`. That will automatically align the `<img>` in the middle of the line (since the `vertical-align` is set to `middle`). This is the most solid fix for vertical-align problems: just changing the line-height.

The final code would look like this:

```
nav.main ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I just tried changing the height from 20 to 80 and it did not work.

Comment: @brybell You need to change the `line-height`, not the `height`. If you do it this way, it's much safer than adding padding, since any changes to the image size would cause the image to shift down if you'd use padding, but this way, it's allowed to resize up to a size of 80px, without breaking anything. Besides, it won't move the other 2 links further up.

Comment: Sorry thats what I meant. In the CSS I posted above I changed `line-height` to 80.

Comment: @brybell You need to make sure that you change the `line-height` to `80px`, not `80`. The `px` suffix is important.

Comment: Yes I know. I got it to work adjusting the padding, but then it moves the other two links too far up.

Comment: @brybell I've added the code you'll need in my answer. Could you try that one?

Answer (score 1):

You have extra padding there. Try this :

```
nav.main ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px; }
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, but then it moves the other two links too far up.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <nav class="main nav-collapse visible-desktop">
       <ul class="inline">
          <!-- <li><a href=".home">Home</a></li> -->
          <li><a href=".our-team">Terms of Service</a></li>
          <li><a href=".privacy">Privacy</a></li>
       </ul>
<a href="#"><img src="images/appstore_button.png" alt="Get the iPhone App Now!" /></a>
          <div id="nav-images"><a href="#"><img src="images/googleplay_button.png" alt="Get the Android App Now!" /></a></div>
    </nav>



#nav { position: relative; }
#nav-images { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0; margin-left: -100px; }
```

Margin left should be 50% of #nav-images width.

Comment: Thank you. Should only the 2nd image be inside the nav-images div? or was that a mistake?

Comment: Everything that needs to be centered has to be inside #nav-images. So, yes - that's mistake.